# R and MATLAB returning different eigenvectors

Tags: r, matlab, eigenvector

I'm missing something obvious, but here goes:

In `R`,

```
dput(M)
structure(c(-2.77555756156289e-16, 9.63770703841896e-16, 0, 9.63770703841896e-16, 
10.6543192562307, 4.11228781751498e-14, 0, 4.11228781751498e-14, 
275.591724761168), .Dim = c(3L, 3L), .Dimnames = list(c("", "", 
""), c("", "", "")))

#thus M is

 -2.775558e-16 9.637707e-16 0.000000e+00
  9.637707e-16 1.065432e+01 4.112288e-14
  0.000000e+00 4.112288e-14 2.755917e+02

eig(M)
$values
[1]  2.755917e+02  1.065432e+01 -2.775558e-16

$vectors
             [,1]         [,2] [,3]
[1,] 5.428099e-34 9.045822e-17    1
[2,] 1.552173e-16 1.000000e+00    0
[3,] 1.000000e+00 0.000000e+00    0
```

But in `MATLAB`

```
[vv,ee] = eig(M)
% hand-copied so ignore the precision)
vv = 
   1.0    -0.    -0.
   0      0      -1
   0      -1     0

ee = 
 %diagonals only
0.0    275.59   10.6543
```

The eigenvalues match up with the  locations where `abs(vv) == 1` ,  but the thing I don't understand is why some eigenvectors are negative one in MATLAB but not in R. 
It makes a big difference, as I'm trying to port [this MATLAB package](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/45356-fitting-quadratic-curves-and-surfaces), (in particular, `parabolafit_direct.m` and `parabolafit_directm.m' )  and the subsequent algorithms are sensitive to the sign of the values.  I checked, and the MATLAB package does produce the correct fitted output (parabolic curve to dataset), while my R-port does not, because of these sign differences.

So, why the difference, and what can I do to modify my `R` code to get the desired signs of the data?

EDIT: I continue to dig into the code to see if these two "negative one" values cancel out in the next set of equations, but haven't seen that yet.

Comment: Are you sure your subsequently applied algorithms depend on the sign? Eigenvectors are undefined up to a scalar constant: if `v` is an eigenvector with eigenvalue lambda, then so is `c*v`, with the same eigenvalue. Eigenvalue-decomposition codes return normalized (length-1) eigenvectors, which still gives you a sign freedom. Both `[0 1 0]` and `[0 -1 0]` are equally valid answers to your question. You need an additional rule to specify which eigenvector you need from the 2 (which is not trivial in case if the Cartesian unit vectors are not eigenvectors, i.e. if the matrix is not diagonal).

Comment: @AndrasDeak I know that part, but if you peek at the referenced code, you'll see that the algorithm adds, subtracts, and multiplies each element of the eigenvector matrix in a myriad of ways.  This means the sign that MATLAB returns depends on the signs of the eigenvectors.   The selection of eigenvalue is made by picking the one with a minimum root of subsequent equations in the function `parabolafit_directM`  .  It's really strange.

Comment: I'm just saying that no algorithm should inherently depend on these signs. What if your eigenvectors are pointing all over the place? In 5d space, for instance? If it's specifically a 3d problem, then there might be some additional constraints...but as I see, the handeness of the two sets of eigenvectors is the same (both are left-handed). I'm saying that if your result is actually different (and not an equivalently good different), then there might be a bug somewhere (in the porting or in the original). Considering that `% ?` is a comment present in the cited codes, it's quite possible.

Comment: @AndrasDeak  yes, in fact it does all come out "in the wash."  At the end of all the `Kappa` and `s,k,t,theta,p` calculations,  (and of course a really stupid bug in my transposition of the code) the same vector of coefficients is returned in both `R` and `MATLAB` , albeit with a global sign change--which does not affect the parabola itself.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @AndrasDeak if you'd like to post your comment as an answer, go anead. If not, I'll quote it w/ a little more info about my specific situation so I can close out this question.

Comment: Thanks, I feel more like that this is a "problem non-existent/not reproducible" question. So if you think that you can use it to instruct future readers, feel free to go ahead and write up what you want:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the important info is in the comments by Andras Deak.  To summarize: as we all (should) know,  eigenvalues and eigenvectors are only unique up to a multiplicative constant.  While in this particular case `R` and `MATLAB` happened to end up with differing signs,  all subsequent matrix operations on the eigenvectors will yield the same result (again,to within sign or constant value).

In my particular case, the final result essentially was:  one answer was `a*x -b =0` and the other was `-a*x + b = 0` .